# It's okay to pass a MySQL query with a lot of spaces?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, t-sql

I'm using this query with PHP:

```php
$query = "UPDATE viajens SET tipo_operacao = $tipo_operacao, 
                             percurso = $percurso, 
                             tipo_cliente = $tipo_cliente, 
                             previsao_inicio = '$previsao_inicio', 
                             previsao_fim = '$previsao_fim', 
                             quilometragem_estimada = '$km_estimada', 
                             origem_empresa_id = $origem, 
                             transportador_empresa_id = $transportador, 
                             motorista_id = $motorista, 
                             veiculo_id = $veiculo1, 
                             reboque1_veiculo_id = $veiculo2, 
                             reboque2_veiculo_id = $veiculo3, 
                             reboque3_veiculo_id = $veiculo4 
                       WHERE id_viajem = $id_viajem;";
```

Parsed view:

```php
$query = "UPDATE viajens SET tipo_operacao = $tipo_operacao,                                percurso = $percurso,                                tipo_cliente = $tipo_cliente,                               previsao_inicio = '$previsao_inicio',                                previsao_fim = '$previsao_fim',                                quilometragem_estimada = '$km_estimada',                                origem_empresa_id = $origem,                                transportador_empresa_id = $transportador,                                motorista_id = $motorista,                                veiculo_id = $veiculo1,                                reboque1_veiculo_id = $veiculo2,                                reboque2_veiculo_id = $veiculo3,                                reboque3_veiculo_id = $veiculo4                                WHERE id_viajem = $id_viajem;";
```

By doing this, will MySQL process this query any slower than an inline query?

Comment: No it will not be any slower, parsing is the fastest part of executing this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, spaces are fine, so stick with what you have if you find it more readable. Stripping out spaces is not something computers have any trouble doing.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't problem with spaces, remember, SQL like others languages, before executing the code, it's parsed to construct AST(*abstract syntax tree* derived from your code) ignoring comments and spaces.

btw, AST contains only necesary information to execute code.